# How do I let the user update a record if the view doesn't contain the record ID?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm a beginner at web development, and I'm trying to make my first basic website with ASP.NET Core. I'm trying to implement a very basic thing, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I have two controller actions methods: LoadBlogPost and SaveBlogPost. LoadBlogPost returns a view that contains an existing blog post model, and SaveBlogPost updates it in the database.

This issue is that in order to update a record in the database, I need the record ID. But the model that SaveBlogPost receives does not contain the ID, because the ID is not part of the view. I've found that I can fix this issue by adding the ID to the view. However I don't want to do that.

How do web developers normally approach this? How do I make it so that the SaveBlogPost method will know the ID of the model it receives, without including it in the HTML view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP is a stateles protocol.
If you're trying to save an existing item, then your view model needs to return an ID which needs to be submitted on form post.

Comment: How do you recommend I do that, if I don't want the ID to be visible in the form?

Comment: You can use a hidden field, `<input type="hidden" ...>`

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You DO send the ID , but you just don't show it .

In the **.cshtml** page for Update, you have to use `input hidden`

```
<form method="post" asp-action="Update">

    <!--Id will be passed to action for updating-->
    <input asp-for="Id" hidden />
```

Then you can use this Id in your actions.